# Automatically set date field end time to +2 hours

Tags: datetime

I am allowing users to pick a start date and time. From that start date and time, I would like to programatically set the end date and time to "start time + 2 hours".

The issues that I'm running into are:

1. How do I collect an end date without showing the user the "end date" field?
2. How do I automatically force the end date to be 2 hours later than the start date?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what part of Drupal you are using to create this form. Is this a webform? A node? Custom module? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, I am just using the standard node creation form.

Comment: One could ask why you'd bother storing an end-date to begin with if you know what it will always be. Regardless: Collect the end date as normal, then set `#access => FALSE` on the form item. That'll hide it from users. Use hook_entity_presave to manually set it's value to whatever you want. Done.

Comment: Also, please don't answer questions about your question by further commenting. Answer them by updating the question.